# LWC - Owl Carousel - Salesforce Community Help

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, carousel

I'm trying to insert in my community page a owl carousel. I've tried to user different codes and i'm stuck in this for days now.

The big problem is that the items of my carousel don't appear on the page.

I will attach my code bellow and prints of the error.
Note that i don't have any errors showing in console.

```
<template>
    <div>test component</div>



    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <h4>1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>5</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>6</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>7</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>8</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>9</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>10</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>11</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>12</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import owlResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/owlTest';
export default class CarouselJS extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {
        if(this.initialRender){return;}
        this.initialRender = true;
        loadScript(this, owlResource + '/js/jquery.min.js')
            .then(e => {
                loadStyle(this, owlResource + '/css/owl.carousel.min.css')
                loadStyle(this, owlResource + '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css')
                                loadStyle(this, owlResource + '/css/owl.carousel.css')

                 .then(e => {
                                         loadScript(this, owlResource + '/js/jquery.min.js')
                                        loadScript(this, owlResource + '/js/owl.carousel.min.js')

                .then(() => {

                   const carousel = this.template.querySelector('div[class="owl-carousel owl-theme"]');
                
                    window.$(carousel).owlCarousel({
                                    loop:true,
                                    margin:10,
                                    nav:true,
                                    responsive:{
                                        0:{
                                            items:1
                                        },
                                        600:{
                                            items:3
                                        },
                                        1000:{
                                            items:5
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                })
          
            })
            })

    }

}
```

Comment: you are missing the lwc dom manual template directive => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives

Comment: Thanks! It's working now, yesterday before posting this question i tried the lwc dom manual but not in the right way!

Comment: no worries, added as an answer to formalize. Happy coding

Comment: Could someone please share what the correct template with lwc:dom="manual" should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [lwc:dom="manual"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives) template directive in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

to use the lwc:dom="manual" you have to leave the div empty and insert it from javascript on the renderedCallback like this:

html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" lwc:dom="manual">
</div>
```

js:

```
const carousel = this.template.querySelector('div[class="owl-carousel owl-theme"]');

carousel.innerHTML = '<div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div><di....';
```